# Troppe negazioni nella frase "Non vinco mai niente"?

Tags: phrase-choice

Mi piace molto l'italiano. Ma non capisco perchè spesso usa tante negazioni. Ieri un mio amico ha detto "Non vinco mai niente". Significa che quando gioca al lotto non vince, ma per dirlo poteva fare frasi più corte, come "Non vinco mai", oppure "Vinco mai", "Certo non vinco". Conosco poco l'inglese, ma mi sembra più logico. Perchè due o tre negazioni non si combattono tra loro?

upgrade

Io cerco su treccani, ma la risposta è più difficile della domanda,
e io non sono intelligente come voi qui. Leggo

"Nell’uso ant., con sign. vicino a quello etimologico, e di solito
in unione o in corrispondenza con un non, equivale a -più-:
Pensa che questo dì mai non raggiorna"

"La negazione di frase è una risorsa che segnala che la situazione
descritta in una frase non sussiste: in altri termini, essa inverte
il valore di verità di una frase dichiarativa"

"La negazione di una frase è espressa tipicamente dall’avverbio non
(- lat. n-n) preposto al predicato: non voglio, non piove. Insieme
a non, l’avverbio mica (- lat. m-cam -briciola-; - grammaticalizzazione)
può intensificare (- intensificatori) la negazione dal punto di vista
pragmatico, respingendo implicazioni o inferenze sollecitate
dal contesto di discorso (Cinque 1976), come quella suggerita
dalla domanda tu hai capito-, a cui risponde (1)"

Cosa non capisco? Na riga si e na riga no! E non voglio dare noia nella
domanda e allora non scrivo quello che non capisco, è lungo.

Chiedo scusa a tutti, non faccio più domande.

Comment: L’uso di più elementi che esprimono negatività viene tipicamente fatto  per dare enfasi alla frase. “*La negazione di una frase è espressa tipicamente dall’avverbio non (< lat. nŏn) preposto al predicato. La funzione di negazione è inoltre svolta da altri tipi di elementi, che non operano sul predicato della frase, nessuno, niente / nulla, mai*” https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/negazione_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/

Comment: Ciao, Micina! Di solito su questo sito ci si aspetta che gli utenti che pongono una domanda abbiano fatto un po' di ricerca su quello che stanno chiedendo, che condividano i dettagli di tale ricerca e che spiegono cosa non è chiara a loro di tutto quello che hanno potuto trovare. Tu sei già un'utente con un po' di esperienza, dunque ti chiedo: hai provato a leggere le spiegazioni su *mai* e *niente* di un dizionario come il Treccani? Se l'hai fatto, cosa non ti è chiara?

Comment: Credo che la confusione nasca dal fatto che in italiano le parole "mai" e "niente" svolgono la stessa funzione che, in altre lingue, è svolta da più parole diverse. Ad esempio, se si considera l'Inglese, "mai" traduce sia *never* che *ever* ("mai dire mai" = " *never say never* ", "hai mai visto...?" = " *Have you ever seen...?* ") e "niente" traduce sia *nothing* che *anything* ("niente è più importante che..." = " *nothing is more important than...* ", "Hai niente da dire?" = " *Have you got anything to say?* ").

Answer (score 6):

Micina, non ti scoraggiare: la cosa è semplice.

In italiano alcune parole, come “niente”, “nulla”, “nessuno”, “mai” e simili, per esprimere una negazione richiedono comunque un “non” (a parte rari casi poetici etc.). Puoi dire:

> In frigo non c'è nulla

> Non c'è nessun problema

mentre non sarebbe buon italiano dire *“In frigo c'è nulla” o *“C'è nessun problema” (l'asterisco indica proprio che sono frasi che non si dicono).

Similmente, si dice:

> Non vinco mai

mentre non si dice *“Vinco mai”.

Per come funziona l'italiano, la vera negazione è data dal “non”. Il resto dice a che cosa si riferisce il “non”. Se hai presente l'inglese, parole come “niente” e “nessuno” si comportano un po' come “anything” e “anyone”. Infatti, se entri in un negozio e non vedi il commesso, potresti chiedere:

> C'è nessuno?

che corrisponde a “Is there anyone?”

A questo punto, volendo, insieme al “non” puoi mettere più d'una di queste parole: “non vinco mai”, “qui non c'è mai nessuno” e così via.

Come osservava giustamente Riccardo in un commento, in certi casi possiamo anche usare “alcuno” al posto di “nessuno” (quando è un aggettivo, cioè se accompagna un nome). Oltre che “Non c'è nessun problema”, possiamo dire anche “Non c'è alcun problema”. Lo stesso per “alcunché” al posto di “niente”. Suonano però un po' più ricercati o scherzosi.

Una curiosità: “mai”, in origine, non aveva un senso negativo (come accenna la tua prima citazione dal Treccani). Viene dal latino *magis*, che vuol dire semplicemente “più” (come quando diciamo “non lo faccio più”).

Comment: "Non c'è nessun problema", al mio orecchio, suona veramente male; preferisco di gran lunga "non c'è problema" o "non c'è *alcun* problema"... ma mi rendo conto che sia un problema mio. ;P

Answer (score 0):

Ciao Micina,
In genere le doppie negazioni vengono usate come rafforzativo per evidenziare qualcosa.

Esempio:

```
Non c'è nessun problema.

Non puoi non ammetterlo.
```

Le ragioni linguistiche per le quali è nato questo costrutto non le conosco.

`Non vinco mai` è corretta, aggiungendo `niente` rafforzi il concetto e dai l'idea di una scocciatura del fatto che non vinci mai.
`Vinco mai` non la trovo corretta.
`Certo non vinco` è una previsione, stai per giocare e dici `Di certo/certamente non vinco` come a far intendere che sei sfortunato e che sai già come andrà a finire.

Comment: Mi sembra che tu stia mettendo insieme situazioni ben diverse. In italiano la parola “niente” (e analoghe, come “nessuno” etc.) _richiede_ quasi sempre una negazione (“non voglio niente”, “non c'è nessuno” e così via). Non sarebbe grammaticale dire *“c'è nessun problema”. Una frase come “non puoi non ammetterlo”, invece, è tutta un'altra cosa: è una vera doppia negazione, un modo diverso per dire “devi ammetterlo”. Ma soprattutto, “non puoi ammetterlo” e “puoi non ammetterlo” sono frasi perfettamente grammaticali, ma di significato diverso.

Comment: Sì, è vero, ci sono molteplici situazioni. Qua ho trovato una spiegazione: https://aulalingue.scuola.zanichelli.it/benvenuti/2019/11/21/la-doppia-negazione/.

Comment: si potrebbe però dire "Non c'è alcun problema" o "Non vinco mai alcunché" ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ciao Micina! Non è tanto difficile, ce la puoi fare, non scoraggiarti. Vediamo se riesco a spiegare in modo semplice.

Alcune lingue usano le "doppie negazioni", l'italiano è una di queste. Quindi per negare qualcosa puoi usare due negazioni. La prima è "non", la seconda è una parola negativa come un pronome/aggettivo (e.g. nessuno) o un avverbio (e.g. mai) che indica assenza, mancanza. Alcuni esempi già citati:

1. *Non(1) vinco mai(2) al lotto*
2. *Non(1) mangio niente(2) di vegano*
3. *Non(1) ho visto nessun(2) film interessante ultimamente*
4. *Non(1) ho incontrato nessuno(2) in libreria*

Tu giustamente pensi: "non mai" significa "sempre", "non niente" significa "tutto". Ragionando in modo logico è così, ma la struttura della doppia negazione non segue queste regole logiche. Allora devi ricordare che "non" seguito da un'altra negazione significa sempre una negazione.

Non devi usare la doppia negazione per forza, quando vuoi negare qualcosa. Guarda, l'ho appena fatto:

1. *Non(1) devi usare la doppia negazione per forza*

Questa è una negazione sola, però il significato rimane negativo. L'importante è che la negazione sola sia "non". Le altre parole negative (e.g. nessuno, niente) hanno regole più complesse, a volte puoi usarle da sole nelle negazioni a volte no, e dipende dalla loro posizione all'interno della frase. Quindi per adesso ignorerei questa parte, e riassumendo direi:

- NON + VERBO è una negazione semplice. Significato finale negativo. E.g. *non mi piace la carne*.
- NON + VERBO + PAROLA NEGATIVA è una negazione doppia. Significato finale negativo o fortemente negativo. E.g. *non mi piace nessuna verdura*.
- PAROLA NEGATIVA da sola, senza il "non". Non usarla se non hai imparato bene le altre due opzioni precedenti.

Infine, chiedevi come mai la lingua italiana si comporta così. Perché esiste la doppia negazione? A quanto pare deriva dal latino (chi l'avrebbe mai detto!). Nel latino classico due negazioni affermano, nel latino volgare due negazioni rinforzano la negazione. Da quest'ultimo caso deriva la doppia negazione dell'italiano corrente.

Fonte: https://accademiadellacrusca.it/it/consulenza/sulla-costruzione-della-frase-negativa-in-italiano/169

Comment: Una piccola nota a margine: non direi che sia giusto o logico pensare che "non mai" corrisponda a "sempre" (anche "talvolta", ad esempio, non è "mai") e "non niente" corrisponda a "tutto" (analogamente al caso precedente, anche "qualcosa" non è "niente").